# Having this Error "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: c#

I was trying to create a windows form with a textbox that will display an auto generated ID Number. But upon executing my program it displays error. Please see codes below.

```
 public void getSerial()
    {
        string SN = string.Empty;
        string qry = "SELECT SerialNumber FROM ID ORDER BY SerialNumber Desc";
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            int id = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString()) + 1;
            SN = id.ToString("00000");
        }
        else if(Convert.IsDBNull(dr))
        {
            SN = ("00001");
        }
        else
        {
            SN = ("00001");
        }
        
        conn.Close();
        txtID.Text = SN.ToString();
    }
```

```
int id = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString()) + 1;
```

This is the part that says the error. "Input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: First off, do not post images with code, post the code itself. Secondly, what is the data type of the serial number in the database?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might get a better response if you edit your question and paste your code as text.

Comment: Please don't apologize but instead [edit] and improve your question. The [ask] can help you as well.

Comment: Really you just need to look at what's in that SerialNumber column. It definitely does not contain integers exclusively.

Comment: Data type of the serial number is nvarchar.

Comment: You're right, it is the SerialNumber data type that causes the error. Got it now.

Answer (score 1):

[According Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-5.0), System.FormatException throws when string is not compliant with style. So, try this:

```
    if(int.TryParse(dr[0].ToString(), NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out id)) 
    { 
        id += 1 
    }
```

Comment: Don't you need a ternary condition after this? I think `TryParse` returns bool (true if success, false if fail).

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I'll edit code